# Problem with .getToken() in AndroidX version

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using the latest version of android (Androidx). The `.setValue(deviceToken)` doesn't identify the `deviceToken` inside `OnSuccessListener` function. I've installed `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'` in `build.gradle`

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() 
{
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) 
    {
     String deviceToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
     Log.e("newToken",deviceToken);
    }
});

RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserId).child("device_token")
                                        .setValue(deviceToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use addOnCompleteListener: It works fine.

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.w("newToken", "getInstanceId failed", task.getException());
                }else{
                    String deviceToken = task.getResult().getToken();
                    Log.e("newToken",deviceToken);
                    RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserId).child("device_token")
                            .setValue(deviceToken);
                }

        }
    });
```